# Python 3, "RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded during compilation"

Tags: python, numpy, exception, parallel-processing, sympy

I'm using python 3.7 with sympy and numpy to find the roots of the derivative of several expressions of one variable all stored in a single file (see below).  I have a C program that spawns numerous processes that run the script below for each expression (I'm finding the derivative roots in parallel; there could be 100+ processes spawned).  Note, the expressions are very complicated and can take quite a long time to evaluate.  This is why I use numpy instead of sympy for finding roots.

Here is the relevant portions of the python code

```
#!/Users/user/anaconda3/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sympy
import numpy
from sympy import Poly

import sys
from sys import argv


currentLine = 0
lineToCheck = int(argv[1]);
expression = ""
with open("file.txt", "r") as myFile:
    for line in myFile:
        if(lineToCheck == currentLine):
            expression = line
            break
        else:
            currentLine += 1

s = sympy.symbols('s')
expression = Poly(sympy.expand(sympy.diff(sympy.simplify(expression))), s)
roots = numpy.roots(expression.all_coeffs())
roots = numpy.sort(numpy.unique(roots[~numpy.iscomplex(roots)]))
```

In some cases (not all the time) when I run this script I get the following error on a subset of the processes that get spawned.

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded during compilation
```

called on line

```
expression = Poly(sympy.expand(sympy.diff(sympy.simplify(expression))), s)
```

My question is the following.  What is causing this error?  I understand what exceeding maximum recursion depth means, but not in the context of compilation.  Does this have to do the python interpreter?  Moreover, does this have to do with spawning too many processes or the expressions being too complicated/long?  If so, how might I fix this error?

Comment: If you don't give the expression that causes the problem.  How can we help?

Comment: You mean the math expression?  There's not a problem with the math expression.  Sometimes the exception will occur on an expression and sometimes it doesn't.  This bug appears to be compile time bug that only occurs occasionally which is why I'm wondering if this has to do with the interpreter.

Comment: Please also post the "faulty" expression, as instructed in [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (mcve)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).